# Show number in a cell - based on a value from another cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

[image: WA76168 Q example]

I need help with the question in the picture.

Can anyone make a formula for me?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the IF command, combined with NE (not equal):

```
IF(NE(RedCellReference,"No"), LeftCellReference, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

For the cell you could also use this formula.

```
=IF(F2 <> "No", B2, "")
```

For the complete column you can use this formula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F2:F <> "No", B2:B, ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the relevant columns are C, D and G, slightly shorter:

```
=ArrayFormula(C1:C*(G1:G<>"nej"))
```

but will return `#VALUE!` if the `C` column entry is Text and requires ColumnD be formatted something like:

```
#;#;;
```

(Blanks in `G` will be populated in `C`.)